# Camunda email service not working

Tags: email, camunda

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-mail/tree/master/examples/print-service

The emails are not going in the above given example by CAMUNDA.

Could anyone please elaborate the point number 8 in the given instructions of How to run this example.

They are saying to send an email before starting process. From where do we have to send the email. Please help.

**Logs :**

```
01-Jun-2018 12:06:11.325 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logError ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: Unknown property used in expression: ${mail.getAttachments().isEmpty()}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'mail'
 org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Unknown property used in expression: ${mail.getAttachments().isEmpty()}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'mail'
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:60)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.el.UelExpressionCondition.evaluate(UelExpressionCondition.java:47)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.el.UelExpressionCondition.evaluate(UelExpressionCondition.java:42)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ExclusiveGatewayActivityBehavior.doLeave(ExclusiveGatewayActivityBehavior.java:59)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityLeave.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityLeave.java:52)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityLeave.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityLeave.java:28)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:91)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:618)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:594)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl$5.callback(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1897)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl$5.callback(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1894)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.continueExecutionIfNotCanceled(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1964)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1913)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1894)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:48)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.execute(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:40)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute$2.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:57)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute$2.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:46)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.continueIfExecutionDoesNotAffectNextOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1958)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:38)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:27)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:91)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:618)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:594)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl$5.callback(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1897)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl$5.callback(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1894)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.continueExecutionIfNotCanceled(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1964)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1913)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1894)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:57)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:27)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:65)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:91)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:604)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:91)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:604)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:91)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:604)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:91)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:618)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:594)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.scopeCreated(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:34)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:50)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:24)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:91)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:112)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:618)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.startWithFormProperties(ExecutionEntity.java:479)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.SubmitStartFormCmd.execute(SubmitStartFormCmd.java:81)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.SubmitStartFormCmd.execute(SubmitStartFormCmd.java:39)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.FormServiceImpl.submitStartForm(FormServiceImpl.java:76)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.sub.repository.impl.ProcessDefinitionResourceImpl.submitForm(ProcessDefinitionResourceImpl.java:183)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocator.java:159)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.invoke(ResourceLocator.java:107)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocator.java:154)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.invoke(ResourceLocator.java:92)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:41)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.filter.EmptyBodyFilter.doFilter(EmptyBodyFilter.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilterSecure(SecurityFilter.java:67)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:58)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:56)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.SecurityActions.runWithAuthentications(SecurityActions.java:40)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier 'mail'
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstIdentifier.eval(AstIdentifier.java:83)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstMethod.invoke(AstMethod.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstMethod.eval(AstMethod.java:75)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstMethod.invoke(AstMethod.java:79)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstMethod.eval(AstMethod.java:75)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstEval.eval(AstEval.java:50)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.AstNode.getValue(AstNode.java:26)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.juel.TreeValueExpression.getValue(TreeValueExpression.java:114)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.ExpressionGetInvocation.invoke(ExpressionGetInvocation.java:36)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:54)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocationInContext(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:87)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:55)
        ... 139 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you:

```
 3. Copy the WAR camunda-bpm-mail.example.print-service-${VERSION}.war into the webapps / deployments folder
 4. Copy the JAR camunda-bpm-mail-core-${VERSION}.jar into the application server lib folder (and make sure that the required dependencies are available - like JavaMail 1.5.5) (e.g. tomcat folder: server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\lib)
 5. Copy the mail configuration src/main/resources/mail-configuration.properties to application server config folder and adjust it (e.g. tomcat folder: server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\conf)
 6. Set the environment variable MAIL_CONFIG to the path where you copied the mail configuration
```

It looks like you've missed some from those steps that are required by **How to run it** section in their [Readme.md](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-mail/blob/master/examples/print-service/README.md)